# multiple login with same username on a website

Tags: web-applications, web

I am signed in to a website on two different machines. I sign out on one of the machines. Strangely, I am 'automagically' signed out on the other machine. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways of handling authentication in any web application , Some web applications like this stores some thing called login Id in the database which will be reused on subsequent login , and when the user logs out , login id in the database gets deleted , and his session will be cleared .

After the user logs out when you refresh the page in other machine it will check whether the person has valid login ID in database or not , if he don't have then it will call logout process  . This is implemented to provide secured browsing to user .

There are some web applications which will allow user to logout all other existing sessions for eg GMail . when you login you can see a link to view existing sessions and allows you tto logout all existing sessions .